# Why can't an electron absorb multiple photons?

Tags: particle-physics, photons, atomic-physics, wave-particle-duality, photoelectric-effect

I am quoting the following phrase from my book

> " ... in Einstein's picture, photoelectric effect arises from the absorption of a single quantum of radiation by a single electron ...  "

My question:

1. Why can't multiple photons strike the electron at the same time?
2. After emission from the metal, why doesn't the electron furthers absorbs photons to reach higher kinetic energy than described by Einstein's photoelectric equation ($K_{max} = h\nu - \phi_0$)?

---

P.S. I apologise for asking a stupid question.

Comment: See also [Photoelectric effect, low frequency light](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/353624/photoelectric-effect-low-frequency-light)

Comment: Multiple photons can certainly strike an electron; that just wiggles the electron, causes 'refractive  index', a bit of phase-retardation, but not absorption unless something OTHER than just same-place-same-time justaposition, i.e. absorption of the photon.